# Counting the number of points in the grid

Tags: r, gis

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

#map
map <- getData('GADM', country='KOR', level=1)
map <- st_as_sf(map)
grid <- map %>% 
  st_make_grid(cellsize = 0.1) %>%
  st_intersection(map)    

#point
point <- read.csv("./Data/C14_Central.csv")
point <- data.frame(
    point$X,
    point$Y
)
point <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(point, data.frame(id=1:711))
point <- st_as_sf(point)

plot(grid)
plot(point, col="red" , add=TRUE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NXUL.png)

I have executed the above code and generated the plot.
Now, I want to create a shapefile containing information about the number of points within the grid of that plot.

I tried using st_join but it didn't work. What should I do?

st_join

Comment: can you share your csv file

Comment: It's made up of three columns. X:Longtitude / Y:Latitude / Name: Name

Comment: Can you create a repoducible example using `dput()` or create a dataframe example of your csv. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example